# The submit button is outside the while loop but it is always moving around after the form has been submitted

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to do a contact form and the form itself is working but everytime when I submitted a reply message, the submit button keeps moving out of position. I have placed the submit button outside the while loop though but it still acts like it is inside of a while loop

I tried to move my brackets around the place but nothing seems to work. I am thinking about using position fixed but I still think that I should be able to get it to work with either absolute or relative. I changed it to relative but the button isn't showing up with position relative

This is my main code:

```
<?php
include_once 'navbar.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
    header("Location: index.php?medical_premium_users=notlogin");
    exit();
} else {
    include_once 'includes/dbh.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM contact_form;";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                           echo "SQL error";
                        } else {


                          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                          $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                          $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                          if ($resultCheck < 1) {
                              echo '<div class="no_enquiries">There are no enquiries yet!</div>';
                          }
                          echo '<form action="medical_enquiries_reply_process.php" method="POST">
                          <table class="medical_enquiries_reply">
                      <tr>
                      <th colspan="3" class="update_title">Welcome to the Administrator\'s Enquiries Reply Section</th>
                      </tr>';

                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo '<tr><th>Ticket:</th><td>'.$row['ticket'].'<input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="',htmlspecialchars($row['ticket']),'"></td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Username:</th><td>'.$row['user_uid'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>First Name:</th><td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Last Name:</th><td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>E-Mail:</th><td>'.$row['email'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Subject:</th><td>'.$row['subject'].'<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="',htmlspecialchars($row['subject']),'"></td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Message:</th><td>'.$row['message'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Date of Message:</th><td>'.$row['date_sent'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Message Reply:</th><td>'.$row['message_reply'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Date of Reply:</th><td>'.$row['date_reply'].'</td></tr>
                               <tr><th>Solved Status:</th><td>'.$row['solved'].'</td></tr>';
                      }




                     echo '</tr>
                        <th>Reply Section</th><td class="reply"><textarea name="reply" placeholder="Message Reply"></textarea></td>
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                      <th>Has this been resolved?</th><td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="resolve" value="No"><label id="no">No</label><input type="radio" name="resolve" value="Yes"><label id="yes">Yes</label></td>
                      </tr>
                       <tr>
                      <th>Reply</th><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply"></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                      </form>';


                        }
}











?>

This is my CSS code:

.medical_enquiries_reply input[type="submit"] {
   position: relative;
   top: 346em;
   left: 41em;
   width: 10%;
   height: 40px;
   border:none;
   background-color: #222;
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #fff;
   cursor:pointer;
   border-radius: 1em;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: The position of the submit button will be dependent on the layout of the table. If you change the `<table>` to `<table border="1">` (just for debugging purposes; this isn't really modern HTML), you will probably get a good idea what is happening. Personally, I would leave the button in a '<div>' outside of the table altogether, and use CSS on to position it

Answer (score 1):

Change the th to td on this line

```
<th>Reply</th><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply"></td>
```

And all the other lines where you start with a th and finish with a td lol

TH is for table headers only and should be closed by the coresponding tag.

A table structure should look like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See how the first tr contains th and all the orthers are td?

The problem you are facing is caused by your HTML structure. The browser is not closing the tags and builds up a weird table. Because the tags are not closed properly, it trys to render a view by closing the tags by him self but he is not closing them at the good place.

I also noticed you had extra TR closing tags in your HTML

[image]

The first one should be a tr opening

So a working table would look like this:

```
<form action="medical_enquiries_reply_process.php" method="POST">
    <table class="medical_enquiries_reply">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3" class="update_title">Welcome to the Administrator\'s Enquiries Reply Section</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Ticket:</td><td>'.$row['ticket'].'<input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="',htmlspecialchars($row['ticket']),'"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td>'.$row['user_uid'].'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>First Name:</td><td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>E-Mail:</td><td>'.$row['email'].'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Subject:</td><td>'.$row['subject'].'<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="',htmlspecialchars($row['subject']),'"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message:</td><td>'.$row['message'].'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date of Message:</td><td>'.$row['date_sent'].'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message Reply:</td><td>'.$row['message_reply'].'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Date of Reply:</td><td>'.$row['date_reply'].'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Solved Status:</td><td>'.$row['solved'].'</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Reply Section</td><td class="reply"><textarea name="reply" placeholder="Message Reply"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Has this been resolved?</td><td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="resolve" value="No"><label id="no">No</label><input type="radio" name="resolve" value="Yes"><label id="yes">Yes</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Reply</td><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Putting `<th>` and `<td>` elements inside the same `<tr>` is perfectly legal HTML, and not really the cause of the issue the OP is having.

Comment: he is starting with a th and closing it with a td ... thats not "legal" at all

Comment: thanks for the assistance! So I guess that the following code here is wrong as well because I have been using th here as well.. I thought that you would need a th for every single heading, not just the main heading

Comment: thanks.... I will check it out.... I should start with a th and closing the th and opening the td and closing the td

Comment: This is very strange because I did it similar to this for my other website and it is working there but not sure why the buttons still keeps moving up the screen after fixing the problems as suggested

Comment: Can you post 2 screen shots showing how it mouves? I am not sure I understand. From the test I have made it seems to stay in place.